# How do I send a file on a self hosted web API and process it on the server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin, self-hosting

I have a self hosted web api using Owin and Katana. I would like to send files (can be pretty large, a few hundred MB) from a sample client, and would like to save these files on the server's disk. Currently just testing the server on my local machine.

I have the following on the test client's machine (it says image here, but it's not always going to be an image):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

class Program
{
    string port = "1234";
    string fileName = "whatever file I choose will be here";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseAddress = "http://localhost:" + port;
        InitiateClient(baseAddress);
    }

    static void InitiateClient(string serverBase)
    {
        Uri serverUri = new Uri(serverBase);
        using(HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = serverUri;
            HttpResponseMessage response = SendImage(client, fileName);
            Console.WriteLine(response);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    private static HttpResponseMessage SendImage(HttpClient client, string imageName)
    {
        using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
        {
            byte[] imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(imageName);
            content.Add(new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(imageBytes)), "File", "samplepic.png");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
            return client.PostAsync("api/ServiceA", content).Result;
        }

    }
```

First, is this the right way of sending a file using POST?

And now here is where I'm really lost. I am not sure how to save the file I receive in the Post method of my ServiceAController which inherits ApiController. I saw some other examples which used HttpContext.Current, but since it's self hosted, it seems to be null.

Answer (score 0):

I would split files into chunks before uploading. 100 Mb is a bit large for single HTTP POST request. Most of web servers also have certain limit on HTTP request size.

By using chunks you won't need to resend all data again if connection times out.

Comment: Hm I see. I'll do that. How do I actually get the data in the Post method of the webapi though? I'm not sure how I can actually grab the file (or parts of file) that was sent over

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter whether you use self hosting or IIS, and whether it is an image file or any type of file.

You can check my answer that will give you simple code to do so

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10765972/71924

Regarding size, it is definitely better to chunk if possible but this gives more work for your clients (unless you also own the API client code) and for you on the server as you must rebuild the file.

It will depend if all files will be over 100MB or if only few. If they are consistently large, I would suggest to look for http byte range support. This is part of the http standard and I am sure you can find somebody who implemented it using WebAPI